# Filebeat Index name

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, filebeat

I deploy filebeat into Kubernetes cluster. I use the lines below changed the index name to "csc-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"

```
 index: "csc-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
setup.template.name: "csc"
setup.template.pattern: "csc-*"
```

I have multiple namespaces in the Kubernetes cluster. I would like to have index names for each namespace. For example, I have namespaces csc-network, csc-ui and csc-workspace.

I would like to have index names as below for each namespace.

```
 index: "csc-network-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
setup.template.name: "csc-network"
setup.template.pattern: "csc-network-*"

 index: "csc-ui-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
setup.template.name: "csc-ui"
setup.template.pattern: "csc-ui-*"

 index: "csc-workspace-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
setup.template.name: "csc-workspace"
setup.template.pattern: "csc-workspace-*"
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Filebeat is deployed as a daemonset in a namespace when you use the official Elastic charts, you can choose to create a helm deployment for each namespace with setting for the index name you are looking for.
https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/filebeat

Comment: this answer does not answer the question above

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this...

```
output.elasticsearch:
  index: "csc-network-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  indices:
    - index: "csc-network-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.contains:
        namespace: "csc-network"
setup.template.name: "csc-network"
setup.template.pattern: "csc-network-*"
...
```